# Why am I unable to extract the information I need from this website using Selenium?

Tags: python, html, amazon-web-services, selenium, web-scraping

TLDR, I can't interact with the "enter your address" field on this website: https://www.mymanatee.org/residents/information, via xpath and selenium, and want to know why.

### **Long version**

---

As mentioned, the information I want is from this [website](https://www.mymanatee.org/residents/information). On the website there is a generic address given, **1112 Manatee Ave W**, that you can search:

[image: Address form filled]

If you scroll down, the information I want is the flood zone "x":

[image: Photo of Field I want]

The code I was using is to interact with the "Input Address" field is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.mymanatee.org/residents/information'
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(10) #makes sure the page fully loads

floodZone = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='inputAddress']")

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Which gives me the following error:

> Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='inputAddress']"}   (Session
> info: chrome=90.0.4430.93)

Bringing me to my question, why can I not extract this information? It isn't because I'm looking for the information before the page loads, because I ran the code line by line through the terminal and still was unable to find it, despite seeing it on the screen in front of me through the driver.

It took me far too long to figure out that I couldn't interact with the site using Selenium and I would like to know if there is a quick way for me to identify this in future so I don't spend needless time trying to interact with something selenium just can't.

### **Solution / Workaround**

---

As promised, I will share the solution I found to get the data I wanted.  Further up the Element tree in the inspector I saw the following: (added line break for readability)

```
<iframe src="https://gis-publicportal.s3-us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com/resident-info.html"
title="Resident Information Tool address lookup" width="100%" height="1850px"></iframe>
```

and used the following code to actually get it:

```
url = 'https://gis-publicportal.s3-us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com/floodzone.html'
driver.get(url)
Situs_address = parcellist[7]
address = Situs_address.replace("Situs Address: ","")

inputaddress = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='inputAddress']")
inputaddress.send_keys(address)
python_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='inputContainer']/div[2]/span[1]/span")
python_button.click()
time.sleep(10)
floodzone = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='fz']")
```

Obviously there is a lot more going on before we get to this step, but all together it works.

### Where I need Help

---

1. Why couldn't I interact with the web page? Can I actually interact with page but am doing something wrong? I know I said several times "Selenium can't", however I am willing to accept a [PEBCAK](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/PEBCAK-problem-exists-between-chair-and-keyboard#:%7E:text=PEBCAK%2C%20one%20of%20many%20terms,a%20common%20class%20of%20problems.) error.
2. If you know of a good community for Selenium, or web scraping with Python, could your recommend it to me? My last option is to ask for help, because I learn better by doing it myself, but sometimes that only goes so far.
3. If this question is written poorly, or could be done better, could you take a second to comment on that?

I searched stackedoverflow, as well as some other resources and even asked the python discord community for help and the ones who responded couldn't help either.

In addition to Selenium, Python, and web-scraping, I am tagging AWS and HTML as the information comes from AWS (with information provided by Arc-GIS), and the page is written in HTML. I was hoping if the python/web-scraping/selenium community was unable to help, maybe the AWS/HTML community could provide some input.

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

I would maybe pivot and look at an arguable better solution. Why do you not call the endpoint yourself, rather than through a webpage?  That way you can get structured JSON data.

```
import requests
resp = requests.get('https://www.mymanatee.org/arcgis02/rest/services/publicportal/MapServer/0/query?f=json&where=((PRIMARY_ADDRESS%20LIKE%20UPPER%20(%271112%25%27)%20OR%20PRIMARY_ADDRESS%20LIKE%20UPPER%20(%27%251112ND%25%27))%20AND%20PRIMARY_ADDRESS%20LIKE%20UPPER(%27%25MANATEE%20AVE%25%27))&outfields=PARCEL_ID%2C%20PRIMARY_ADDRESS%2CCITY%2C%20HASHID&returnGeometry=false&returnTrueCurves=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnZ=false&returnM=false&returnDistinctValues=false&returnExtentsOnly=false&orderByFields=PRIMARY_ADDRESS')
```

You can then get a lovely JSON response:

```
resp.json()
{
   "displayFieldName":"COMMNAME",
   "fieldAliases":{
      "PARCEL_ID":"PARCEL_ID",
      "PRIMARY_ADDRESS":"PRIMARY_ADDRESS",
      "CITY":"CITY",
      "HASHID":"HASHID"
   },
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"PARCEL_ID",
         "type":"esriFieldTypeString",
         "alias":"PARCEL_ID",
         "length":12
      },
      {
         "name":"PRIMARY_ADDRESS",
         "type":"esriFieldTypeString",
         "alias":"PRIMARY_ADDRESS",
         "length":36
      },
      {
         "name":"CITY",
         "type":"esriFieldTypeString",
         "alias":"CITY",
         "length":15
      },
      {
         "name":"HASHID",
         "type":"esriFieldTypeString",
         "alias":"HASHID",
         "length":24
      }
   ],
   "features":[
      {
         "attributes":{
            "PARCEL_ID":"3222400109",
            "PRIMARY_ADDRESS":"1112 MANATEE AVE E ",
            "CITY":"BRADENTON",
            "HASHID":"3222400109000-3800801871"
         }
      },
      {
         "attributes":{
            "PARCEL_ID":"3297510004",
            "PRIMARY_ADDRESS":"1112 MANATEE AVE W ",
            "CITY":"BRADENTON",
            "HASHID":"3297510004000-4282525129"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Way less overhead. You could construct your own url query by deconstructing what was sent here:

```
((PRIMARY_ADDRESS LIKE UPPER ('1112%') OR PRIMARY_ADDRESS LIKE UPPER ('%1112ND%')) AND PRIMARY_ADDRESS LIKE UPPER('%MANATEE AVE%'))&outfields=PARCEL_ID, PRIMARY_ADDRESS,CITY, HASHID&returnGeometry=false&returnTrueCurves=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnZ=false&returnM=false&returnDistinctValues=false&returnExtentsOnly=false&orderByFields=PRIMARY_ADDRESS
```

Comment: I found that as well in the Network tab of the inspector.  If you take the URL in your request and change
>query?f=json
to
>query?f=html
you an even more lovely HTML form which Selenium can point to as well. I get it, you are showing me a way to remove Selenium all together and just use r.  I would have to take the address, do a regex to grab the house numbers, and then another to grab the remainder of the address.  or split the string on spaces, grab the next index after situs for the house, and then do something else to add the street name.  Thanks another way to look at it.

Comment: I've looked at the code and it looks like about 300 lines of very well commented javascript which could very easily be duplicated in Python as it's mainly regex, split string and replacing characters to make it consistent.  I reckon it's maybe 60 minutes to duplicate the whole thing and you'd have a very fast, highly reliable function you could use much more cleanly than scraping.  It would be worth the effort in the long run and anything you don't understand, a quick google would work or ask another question.  Regex's will be broadly identical..

Comment: I should say 300 lines including comments and lots of white space.